# JQuery Sum of multiple inputs with the same class not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the sum of a specific class of input fields and dump the sum into a separate input field and its not working as expected.

When I try it with a single input field to add, it works, but when there are multiple inputs with the same class to sum together, it results in NaN.

Here is a demo of what I am trying to do and it NOT working.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQ7RM8CBI064

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Convert the string to number first before adding the values

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues. You were sum was carrying over to every change (rather than just the 3 numbers). And you were not handling empty inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add').change(function() {
        var sum = 0; // Recompute total sum per change.
        $('.addprice').each(function() {
               var x = $(this).val(); // Get the number and make sure it exists.
               sum += parseFloat(x || 0); 
        });
        $('#addsubTotal').val(sum);
        alert(sum);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following validations

- Check whether each input is a number or not
- Make sum to zero before each loop addition

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var sum = 0;
 $('.add').change(function() {
        sum = 0;
  $('.addprice').each(function() {
            if($(this).val()){
               sum += parseFloat($(this).val()); 
           }
  });
  $('#addsubTotal').val(sum);
  alert(sum);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Input field: <input type="text" class="add addprice" value=""></p>
<p>Input field: <input type="text" class="add addprice" value=""></p>
<p>Input field: <input type="text" class="add addprice" value=""></p>

Sum: <input type="text" id="addsubTotal" value=""></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have made some changes. try this code i hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.add').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
            $('.addprice').each(function() {
            console.log(!(isNaN($(this).val())))
            if((!(isNaN($(this).val()))) && $(this).val())
            {              
            sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val()); 
            }
            });
            $('#addsubTotal').val(sum);
            alert(sum);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Input field: <input type="text" class="add addprice" value=""></p>
    <p>Input field: <input type="text" class="add addprice" value=""></p>
    <p>Input field: <input type="text" class="add addprice" value=""></p>

    Sum: <input type="text" id="addsubTotal" value=""></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```